# Horizontal centering of "writing-mode"

Tags: html, css

I use the CSS `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` within my table's `<th>` to write the table headers vertically. However the text is left aligned. How can I center the text horizontally within the table's cell?

```css
th:not(:first-child) {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>...</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: You must post your working code to make this a useful post for this site. This isn't just a question for you but alsos a reference for future users.

Comment: Fantastic, it does. If you add it as an answer I'll tick it

Answer (score 0):

In order to center the text horizontally, you can use `text-align: center;`.
Like this :

```
<th style="writing-mode: vertical-rl; text-align: center;">
     Text
</th>
```